# Unable to apply css in moSync

Tags: css, cross-platform, mosync

I want to learn cross platform application development.i am using moSync tools for it.it uses html,javascript,css. for native application they provide their own api which is written in javascript.i have run simple demo application.but i want to apply css to code but that is not reflected .i dont understand why it is not applying  my css code.i included my css into html as given below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="Screen" type="text/css">
```

here is my css code where in i want to apply margin to div

```
    .edittext
    {
        margin:50px 0px 0px 20px;
    }

    here is my html code

   <div class="edittext" 
    id="ed1"
    widgetType="EditBox" 
    data-placeholder="Title">                           
   </div>
```

Comment: your class applying try this http://jsfiddle.net/BQT8J/

Comment: are you sure your css file is included?

Comment: yes.i have included my css file <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="Screen" type="text/css"> under <head> section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your css File is included in your project.

```
<div class="edittext" id="ed1" widgetType="EditBox" data-placeholder="Title">Add some text                  </div>
```